# ElasticSearch delete_by_query: Trying to create too many scroll contexts

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fix this error while running `delete_by_query` API on AWS ElasticSearch:

> Trying to create too many scroll contexts. Must be less than or equal to: [500]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_open_scroll_context] setting.

After going through few posts I have some basic idea as to what scroll-context is, however, my knowledge of "open scroll contexts" still remains murky.

I have a few questions regarding my understanding:

- Does it mean that the API will open up a scroll context for the specified time (scroll = some period) and after processing (within the stipulated scroll time), open up a new context?
- If so, do the previously processed contexts remain open till the API terminates?
- I have 4 java EC2 instances running each of will execute `delete_by_query` API. Can this also cause too many scroll contexts to remain open? or it's unrelated?

Please do shed some light if there's anything lacking.

Coming to fixing the error:

The straight forward solution would be to increase the `search.max_open_scroll_context` parameter, however it has negative side effects as mentioned in this [document's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-context) tip/note section.

Are there any other solutions?

- Can increasing the batch size per scroll help?

Edit: The EC2 instances (2 in east-1 and 2 in west-2) are running a spring application at a frequency of 1s (this frequency is deliberate and can't be changed due to some restrictions), listening to SQS (in corresponding regions) for messages, and `delete_by_query` will use act upon these messages (delete based on some parameter from the message received).
Note: The SQS has considerable amount of data coming in.

Comment: Can you explain in more details how your 4 EC2 instances call the delete by query API, for doing what and at which frequency?

Comment: So basically, if I get this right, in the worst case you potentially have four delete by query calls running pretty much every second?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And do you know on average how many records get matched/deleted by each query?

Comment: Currently no documents get matched for the API call, but there are precisely 822570 documents in the index.

Comment: So the next time you get the following error `Trying to create too many scroll contexts`, can you run `GET _tasks?actions=*byquery&detailed` and update your question with the results, please?